# Numerical Integration of PointCollection in C#

Tags: c#, point, numerical-integration

I have a PointCollection, which contains data of a sine, that i have produced.
Now i have to build the numerical integral of this data and plot it together with the sine data (per Polyline).
I´ve found this function on stackoverflow, but it´s not really working :(
The integral of sin(x) should normally be -cos(x), but what i get is -sin(x) and I have to scale the ypos, but in a similar interpolation function, it works without scaling. Has someone an idea, where my problem is?

**red: original noisy data, blue: interpolated data green: integrated data**
[image: pic]

```
private PointCollection Numerical_Integration(PointCollection input_data)
{
      PointCollection integrated_data = new();
      for (int i = 1; i < input_data.Count; i++)
      {
            double integrated_ypos = (input_data[i].Y + input_data[i - 1].Y) / 2 * (input_data[i].X - input_data[i - 1].X);
            integrated_data.Add(new Point(input_data[i].X, integrated_ypos/5+300));
      }
      return integrated_data;
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the magic numbers `y/5+300` ?

Comment: That is the scaling, I´ve talked about. And I dont understand, why I need it to fit in my canvas.

Comment: Is your problem that positive _y_ values point downwards (pixel coordinates) and your input data have _y_ values pointing upwards as in a normal cartesian coordinate system?

Comment: That shouldn´t be a problem, because the original and interpolated data are shown correct. And all these functions get the same input data, except the integration function. That get´s the interpolated data.

Comment: The conversion from the cartesian coordinate system to the pixel coordinate system happens in my function for reading the data from a csv file.

Comment: All this is information you need to include in the original question. Please [edit] the question and include the minimum code needed to reproduce the problem. Also check if the problem is numeric, or graphical to focus the question more.

Comment: You are trying to use the [Rectangle method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method) for numerical integration, but there's a basic flaw in your code: each point in `integrated_data` is supposed to accumulate the area of **all the previous rectangles** plus the area under the current rectangle at point `i` -- your `integrated_ypos` never adds in the previously accumulated values.  Your code should look something like `integrated_ypos = (i == 0 ? 0 : integrated_data[i-1]) + (input_data[i].Y + input_data[i - 1].Y) / 2 * (input_data[i].X - input_data[i - 1].X)`.

Comment: That looks to be the basic problem with your implementation here.  There may also be bugs with scaling factors (not sure about the `/ 2` and the `/5+300` looks fishy).  That being said, the rectangle method is one of the least accurate algorithms for [numerical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration), the trapezoidal rule as suggested by @JohnAlexiou will produce much better results.

Comment: Also, you wrote: *I´ve found this function on stackoverflow, but it´s not really working :(* -- where did you find it?  If you are using code that another stack overflow contributor wrote, you should credit them as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.

Answer (score 1):

This uses the standard trapezoidal rule for integration.

#### Program

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Integrate f(x) = 10*cos(x) between x=0..4π
        var curve = new PointCollection();
        const int n = 180;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            float x = (float)( (4 * Math.PI * i) / n );
            float y = (float)( 10 * Math.Cos(x) );
            curve.Add(new PointF(x, y));
        }

        var integral = Integrate(curve, 0f);

        // Compare results to 10*sin(x)
        float max_error = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            float x = (float)((4 * Math.PI * i) / n);
            float iy_expect = (float)(10 * Math.Sin(x));
            float iy_actual = integral[i].Y;
            float iy_error = Math.Abs(iy_actual - iy_expect);
            max_error = Math.Max(max_error, iy_error);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Steps = {n}, Max Error = {max_error}.");
    }

    public static PointCollection Integrate(PointCollection inputData, float integrationConstant = 0)
    {
        float h;
        var integral = new PointCollection();
        integral.Add(new PointF(inputData[0].X, integrationConstant));
        for (int i = 1; i < inputData.Count; i++)
        {
            h = inputData[i].X - inputData[i - 1].X;
            float iy = integral[i - 1].Y + h * (inputData[i].Y + inputData[i - 1].Y) / 2;
            integral.Add(new PointF(inputData[i].X, iy));
        }
        return integral;
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Steps = 180, Max Error = 0.004058838.
```

As you can see from the output, the error is pretty good considering the resolution of the input curve.

#### Error analysis

Considering increasing number of steps, here is the max errors I am reporting:

```
 Steps           Error
    16       0.5194054
    32       0.1288424
    64      0.03214836
   128     0.008034706
   256     0.002008438
   512    0.0005044937
  1024    0.0001296997
  2048     3.71933E-05
  4096    1.049042E-05
  8192    1.716614E-05
 16384    1.335144E-05
 32768    2.288818E-05
```

As you can see I hit the limit of precision for `float` numbers at about 4096 steps.

Comment: [`PointCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.pointcollection.add?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) represents a collection of [`Point`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.point?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) structs whose [coordinates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.point?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#properties) are `double` not `float`.